# if [ "$state" == 1 ] ... is never equal to 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a toggle script for my touchpad which I'll later bind to a key combination, unfortunately I can't get the script working right. I assume I have my variables declared wrong or something but if someone can point it out for me, I'd really appreciate it. My device is listed as :

```
ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad               id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Here's my script so far :

```
#!/bin/bash

device="13"
state='xinput list-props '$device' | grep -i "device enabled" | grep -o "[01]$"'

if [ "$state" == 1 ]; then
    xinput disable $device
else
    xinput enable $device
fi
```

It seems the if statement doesn't work the way I intended and is never equal to 1

Comment: FYI -- `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside `[ ]` in all POSIX-compliant shells; the standardized string comparison operator is `=`. And quote your expansions: `xinput disable "$device"`; see http://shellcheck.net/ for automated feedback.

Comment: With all testing that you are not sure about, you can simply put set -xv at the start of the script to see what your values are actually set to before testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
state='xinput list-props '$device' | grep -i "device enabled" | grep -o "[01]$"'
```

use:

```
state=`xinput list-props "$device" | grep -i "device enabled" | grep -o "[01]$"`
```

Take care.

Comment: you forget to fix `'$device'` in your fix

Comment: My bad, fixed. Thanks fghj.

Comment: Can't believe I just had the ` and ' symbol mixed up. I had to change the quotes around $device from '$device' to "$device" as well but it's all working now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Better to use `$()` than backticks -- less surprising behavior if you need to nest them or include literal double-quotes. Thus: `state=$(xinput list-props ...)`

Comment: Also, `$( )` is far harder to confuse with regular single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using `state` later, just do:

```
if xinput list-props "$device" | grep -i "device enabled" | grep -q -o '1$'; then
   xinput disable "$device"
else
   xinput enable "$device"
fi
```